# Google Earth: Unix email

Tags: debian, email, firefox, chrome

mailto: .. attach= is not working for firefox nor chrome, so can't email a .klm file from Google Earth?

**I love having Google Earth on Debian, but** when I try to email a **`.klm`** view file using **`File`** | **`Email`** | **`Email view...`**
and select `web browser mailto: handler`:

[image]

I get the following error message:

[image]

I'm not seeing this error message in Windows 10.  Instead it creates the email as expected with the attachment.

**Here's what I've already tried to fix this:**

**1)** Fixed the environment (a couple of places to be sure):

```
# cat /etc/environment 
BROWSER=/opt/firefox/firefox
```

and

```
# tail  -2 /etc/.bash.shared 
export BROWSER="/opt/firefox/firefox"
```

Now when I open terminal I get this:

```
$ env | grep BROWSER
BROWSER=/opt/firefox/firefox
```

---

**2)** Also I tested both Firefox and Chrome to see if the `attach=` worked in a **`mailto:`** URL, but so far I can't seem to this to work.  I'm trying to browse to a URL something like these:

```
mailto:me@mydomain.com?subject=xx&body=yy&attach=%22%2fhome%2fhoward%2fDesktop%2fphpmyadmin.pdf%22
```

(where the URL encoding is %22 is for a double quote (") and %2f is for a slash (/)).

I've also tried `@attachment=` rather than `@attach=`.

Both Thunderbird and Chrome open a new email window, and the subject and body work as expected, but the attachment is not present.

---

**So first, I think I need to get `@attach=` to work with Firefox (or Chrome), but how?**

---

**I'm using:**

- Debian 9.9 (x86-64) (Linux Kernel 4.9.0-9-amd64)
- Cinnamon 3.2.7  with
- Google Earth 7.1.4.1529
- Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 (64 bit)  / Chrome 76.0.3809.100 (64-bit)

---

Comment: I don't think that including an attachment via a `mailto:` url works with any mailer program. Are you sure that's how GoogleEarth tries to pass it?

Comment: Try running `strace -s1024 -fe trace=execve -p [pid of google earth]` in a separate window while trying to email that `.kml`, and that will tell you exactly what it's trying to run. A solution could be to point the `BROWSER` envvar to a wrapper script that handles it.

Comment: @mosvy, I see two processes: google-earth and googleearth-bin. In a bash window I run: `ps -C google-earth` and `ps -C googleearth-bin` and this gives process ids 26862 and 26873. Then I run strace -s1024 -fe trace=execve -p 26862 and this gives, "strace: Process 26873 attached" and for `... -p 26873` ".. with 26 threads", and then in Google Earth, when I do `File | Email | Email view...` and select web browser mailto: handler nothing happens in the bash window. If I hit ^C one or a bunch of processes are detached & the bash prompt returns. Is there a system call other than execve to test for?

Comment: @mosvy, ... belay that question a little bit, I found the `strace -c` option and am busy trying to see what other calls might be related, but this will take some time for me to sort out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **workaround** to get a `*.kmz` file from Google Earth in GMU/Linux for your current location:

- Create a **push pin** in the view you're at.
  (The name doesn't matter, but if you name it your filename below will be that name.)
- Then right click on this push pin and select '**Save Place As**'.
- Then you can attach this ***.kmz** file to an **email** to send it to someone.

*(You can sometimes select File | Save, but this doesn't always work.)*